# Improve search functionality

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)
>   [Search for SO questions by words in the title is failing (purpose: trying to find question before i ask a duplicate)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/search-for-so-questions-by-words-in-the-title-is-failing-purpose-trying-to-find)

> Related:
>
> - [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)
> - [Searching for similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26684/searching-for-similar-questions)
> - [Asking questions brings up better Related questions than search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29508/asking-questions-brings-up-better-related-questions-than-search)
> - [Search box vs Question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/search-box-vs-question-title)
> - [Why does (insert favorite search engine here) get better search results than SO, SF, or SU's own search function?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11387/why-does-insert-favorite-search-engine-here-get-better-search-results-than-so)

As you can see tell from personal experience and see from the related questions above the "search" feature kinda sucks, while the "Related questions" is actually pretty good. This is because "search" searches in the title, question text, and in all the answers. "Related questions" searches only the title.

I propose to either stop searching the answers too, or weigh the titles **a lot more** than the contents, and the contents a lot more than the answers (after all you're searching for questions 99% of the time).

Try [searching for "Programmer Cartoon"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=programmer+cartoon) on stackoverflow. You're obviously looking for [What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon-closed), but what is the first result? [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke-closed).

You'll be wondering why it's the first result since it really has nothing to do with cartoons. That's a good question. The answer is that **in the *third* page of answers [one single answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/788760#788760) mentions the word cartoon**.

I'm aware that you can just use `intitle:1`, but how many people know that you'll get much more relevant results with it? The current system can be greatly improved.

Comment: So you're saying you stop looking at the search results when the very first return doesn't match what you had in mind. It's the second one down. What's wrong with reading the list?

Comment: @random: are you seriously saying that results should not be ordered based on relevance, because people can just read the list? I hope google will never hire you

Comment: @Koper: @random is right. Relevance is subjective, and your query got you on the second place the question you wanted. That's not bad at all.

Comment: When you go in prejudiced about what the search results should be bringing up in a certain order, nothing is relevant to you. @kop

Comment: Your duplicate question is a duplicate of a duplicate. Wow!

Comment: However many times it's been suggested, the title of this question "Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool" is still true.  Why?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like stackoverflow's own search function, you could [use Google instead](http://www.google.com.ar/search?hl=es&rlz=1C1GGLS_esAR350AR350&q=programmer+cartoon+site:stackoverflow.com&btnG=Buscar&meta=&aq=f&oq=).

---

The proposal you are making [has been already been made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/search-for-so-questions-by-words-in-the-title-is-failing-purpose-trying-to-find) and implemented. Trust us, search works better than it used to.

Answer (score 3):

If having the desired result in position #2 is so infuriating to you, why not put your search term in quotes?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22programmer+cartoon%22

I do this all the time when doing Google searches to get better results on phrases. Why would our search engine be any different?